# where to put firebase-messaging-sw file in angular app

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I am struck while registering service worker. I have created a sample project where i have added `firebase-messaging-sw.js` file at root level like this

```
<script src="/firebase-messaging-sw.js"></script>
```

at root level and `manifest.json` file later i did `grunt serve` after launching app, I'm able to register service worker and token is generated , and it is working fine .

after that I tried Implementing that feature in actual working project , I have added at root level giving
Uncaught Error: [$http://injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module App due to:
Error: [$http://injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module lazyModel due to:
Error: [$http://injector:nomod] Module 'lazyModel' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument. this Error.

and also i have added manifest.json file at root level its not loading in browser .

Now the question is for " grunt serve " project is working fine , for " grunt build " generated a dist added that that in war file below the WEB INF . why it is  not working for grunt build ??

dist is not not packging the file.

for my actual project the path is http://localhost:8080/XXXXXX/index.html#/core/login i am using this path "grunt build " generated dist .

for my sample project http://localhost:9000/#/ used grunt serve.

Directory structure[image]

Comment: can you provide the directory structure and full error log?

Comment: Hi! Did you find any workaround to this? I am also working on this. Thanks.

Comment: what problem your facing?? are  you able to install service worker??

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/issues/109you can refer this link for the solution.

Comment: if any one found the solution of this question

Answer (score 0):

Try check if all the other dependencies are loaded correctly?

As your error says "Module 'lazyModel' is not available", try to locate at the positions where it has been used or required.

Answer (score -1):

Use a [service worker precache](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache). It's a module that generates a service worker responsible for caching all the static resources in your application.

It generates a service-worker.js file right in your root folder. You can see the output also includes the total size and number of assets that are cached. This corresponds to the total number of resources that your application shell contains.

[Here](https://houssein.me/progressive-angular-applications) is a blog that might help.

Cheers!